# Fortran + Openmp more slow that sequential

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have this sequential code in Fortran. My problem is, when I put Openmp directives, the paralleled code is more slow than the sequential, and I don't see the error.

```
REAL, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: current, next
ALLOCATE ( current(TOTAL_Z), next(TOTAL_Z))

CALL CPU_TIME(t1)

!$OMP PARALLEL SHARED (current, next) PRIVATE (z)
DO t = 1, TOTAL_TIME
    !$OMP  DO SCHEDULE(STATIC, 2)
    DO z = 2, (TOTAL_Z - 1)
        next(z) = current (z) + KAPPA*DELTA_T*((current(z - 1) - 2.0*current(z) +      current(z + 1)) / DELTA_Z**2)
    END DO
    !$OMP END DO
    current = next
END DO

CALL CPU_TIME(t2)

!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

TOTAL_Z, TOTAL_TIME, KAPPA, DELTA_T, DELTA_Z are constants.
When I run the paralleled code, I see in htop and my 2 cores are working at 100% 
In sequential code, CPU_TIME is 79 seg and in paralleled is 132 seg 
Thank

Comment: Your code has a race condition.  All threads execute the outer loop with index variable `t`.  In that loop all threads execute the assignment `current = next`.  All threads are writing to the same memory location without any synchronisation.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been experiencing the same problem.

It seems that using cpu_time() is not suitable to measure the performance of multi-threaded code. cpu_time() will add the total time of all the threads which is likely to increase with increasing number of threads.

I've found this in another forum,
http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/281897

You should use system_clock() or omp_get_wtime() functions to get a more accurate timing of your routine.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably slow because of the threads are contending to access the `shared` variables.  If you can change it to use `reduction` it would likely be faster.  But that might not be easy since the calculation for "current" accesses multiple array elements.

Answer (score 1):

depending on the number of iterations, you might also be facing a problem with false-sharing on the nest array.  Since the chunk size for the distribution of the DO loop is rather small, the cache line for nest(z), nest(z+1), nest(z+2), nest(z+3), etc might be thrashing between the L1/L2 caches of the CPU.

Cheers,
        -michael